# Reparenting nodes with Godot Editor Scripts

Tags: godot

I'm trying to place each node in a scene in it's own parent node. I made a script that inherits from EditorScript and it creates the parents, but the nodes are disappearing from the editor tree view after calling `reparent()`. The meshes themselves are still visible in the editor view however. How do I reparent nodes in an EditorScript tool?

```
@tool
extends EditorScript

func _run():
    var meshes = get_scene().get_children();
    for node in meshes:
        # make node
        var parent: Node3D = Node3D.new()
        parent.name = node.get_name()+"_root"
        # add to scene
        get_scene().add_child(parent)
        parent.owner = get_scene()
        #reparent mesh to new node
        node.reparent(parent);
        node.owner=parent
        #get_scene().print_tree_pretty() # <-- shows the nodes, but they're not visible in the editor tree
        print(meshes.size())
        #return
```

---

For clarification, I've got multiple meshes on the root level, and I want to place each mesh in it's own node and add a convex collision to it, to convert the scene to a Mesh Library

Comment: Here's a workaround if you just want to add collision meshes to many meshes: Select all meshes, use the mesh>Create Trimesh Static body tool, then in an editorscript call `col.set_shape(ConcavePolygonShape3D.new())` on all meshes in the scene.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `owner` is how Godot know to which "scene" a `Node` belongs.

More precisely a `Node` is considered a "scene" if it is to be persisted on its own file (and so it has the path of an associated `PackedScene` in its `scene_file_path` in Godot 4, or `filename` in Godot 3).

If the `owner` does not match with the currently edited scene, then it must either be a temporary node (that will not be persisted, and will not be shown in the editor), or belong to a sub-scene (which will be persisted separately). *And to be clear, a `Node` child of the currently edited scene is considered a "scene"... by the means I said above... The children of the sub-scene are shown in the editor according to the "Children Editable Flag" bundled in the `PackedScene`.*

You are setting the `owner` to a `Node` that is not considered a "scene":

```
node.owner=parent
```

Make the scene root the `owner` of the `Node`s instead:

```
node.owner = get_scene()
```

Comment: Setting the scene as owner did work. Is this mentioned somewhere in the docs?

Comment: @MrSomeone Not in detail. See [`owner`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_node.html#class-node-property-owner).